# haproxy nested conditions for acl

Tags: haproxy

I need nested ACL conditions

```
acl route1 hdr_sub(host) -i abc.com hdr_sub(host) -i xyz.com 
acl route2 path_beg /m1
acl route3 path_beg /m2


use backend back1 if route1 (route2 or route3)

// essentially  
route1 AND (route2 OR route3)
```

to match backends. What would be the correct HA code equivalent to this ?

Answer (score 11):

Rules in a single ACL are ORed, so, you can combine the `route2` and `route3` rules with this:

```
acl route2 path_beg /m1
acl route2 path_beg /m2

use backend back1 if route1 route2
```

Conditions also support the `||` operator, but not parenthetical grouping for precedence, so `a b || c` means `(a and b) or (c)`, which isn't equivalent to what you want... so if you don't want to combine the ACLs as shown above, you would need this...

```
use backend back1 if route1 route2 || route1 route3
```

...which is not exactly intuitive.

Or this:

```
use backend back1 if route1 route2
use backend back1 if route1 route3
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the first line? Should that say `route1` for the name? Or maybe `route2` and `route3`

Answer (score 1):

*See HA manual Section **7.2. Using ACLs to form conditions***

You can declare an ACL to group those two conditions :

```
acl route2_or_route3 path_beg /m1 /m2
```

And use it in your rule:

```
use backend back1 if route1 route2_or_route3
```

Which means `route1` and (`route2` or `route3`).

> Conditions in an ACL are grouped by an implicit logical `OR`.
>
> Conditions in an action rule are grouped by an implicit logical `AND`.

Comment: please note that the HA manual, which states things quite clearly, uses only the terms `path` and `hosts`. There's no such things as "route" which first designates network routes and got overly misused in javascript frameworks documentations instead of *url path*. Caution is advised with generalization of names, as this makes searches harder.